# Int Object is Not Callable

Tags: python

When I type this code it says 'int object is not callable' for line 5

```
import numpy
s = 0
def arccot(x,n):
    for k in range(0,n):
        s += ((-1**k)(x**(-1-(2*k)))/1+(2*k))
    print (s)


arccot(5,5)
```

Answer (score 6):

That's because you try to call `(-1**k)` as a function by placing `(x**(-1-(2*k)))` after it:

```
(-1**k)(x**(-1-(2*k)))
```

You need to put a mathematical operator (`+`, `*`, etc.) between the two:

```
(-1**k)+(x**(-1-(2*k)))
(-1**k)*(x**(-1-(2*k)))
...
```